# Average width of the male body

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy, measurement

I've been looking for the average width (at widest point) of the average American male body but couldn't find it anywhere so far.

When I say "widest point", I mean that if you draw a rectangle (that gives X for width and Y for height) around the whole body, **all of it should fit inside the rectangle**, whether the shoulders are wider than the hips or vice-versa. I'm looking for the average value of X (arms against body).

If the hips are the widest point inside the rectangle, the width should contain the width of the hands that are against them.

[image: body width]

Do you have (or know where I can find) that information?

Comment: I am so wondering now whether in the USA the average widest point would be the shoulder or the belly. Did you mean the point for which the average is the widest or the average widest point (consider the the widest point might be should for one person, belly for another and butt for yet another person)?

Comment: @Remi.b i meant at widest point

Comment: Let me re-ask my question. Do you mean measuring size at shoulder, belly and butt and then each of them and consider the largest number or do you mean taking for each individual the largest of these three values and then average those max values? Note that even once this is clarified, I am not sure anyone will be willing to really look and analyse such data for you.

Comment: why exactly are you asking that? What will you do with that information? If you explain a bit about your real problem, maybe we can help with it. Right now it looks like XY problem http://xyproblem.info/ For example, for health studies people use waist circumference. Caskets come in 28 inch wide or 31 inch wide options (quick google)

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I don't see any interesting Biology here as defined for this stack.

Comment: Widest as seen from the front, or from the side?  And if from the front, do you measure at the shoulders, or include the arms?  And if the arms, how are they held?  (That is, some people with a good deal of chest muscle have their arms out at an angle.)

Comment: hi. thanks for clarification. You might get some answers, but i urge you to describe your problem fully, not just request for X.

Comment: @maashatheytaz won't this mostly just covary with weight? More overweight people will have on average wider bodies. This seems a curious variable to attempt to measure.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question, but highly doubt that anyone has an empirical answer because the information indeed isn't biologically relevant (and hence nobody has it). I could imagine it being interesting for game or furniture design, or architecture. As @aaaaaa said, it does sound like an XY problem and you should probably go back to the X and figure out which Stack Exchange site can provide you with information that might solve your problem.

Comment: @NatWH that's why I am asking for an average. They are anatomy statistics made out there, so if we a range, we can extract an average.

Comment: @maasha theytaz: I don't think an average is going to be all that useful, because there are distinct body types (mesomorph, ectomorph, &c).  Add on the effect of either obesity or weight training, and it seems like few people would actually be close to the average.